# ModelForm has no model class specified while using model form

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-models, django-forms

> > path('', include('farmingwave.urls')),   File "F:\farm\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
> > urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "C:\Users\Mohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib_*init*_.py",
> > line 127, in import_module
> > return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import   File
> > "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File
> > "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> > File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
> > File "", line 790, in
> > exec_module   File "", line 228, in
> > *call_with_frames_removed   File "F:\farm\fwave\farmingwave\urls.py", line 3, in 
> > from . import views   File "F:\farm\fwave\farmingwave\views.py", line 3, in 
> > from .forms import ContactForm   File "F:\farm\fwave\farmingwave\forms.py", line 3, in 
> > from django.forms import contactForm ImportError: cannot import name 'contactForm' from 'django.forms'
> > (F:\farm\lib\site-packages\django\forms_*init**.py)
>
> my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from .forms import contactForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = contactForm()
    else:
        form = contactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            Phonenumber = form.cleaned_data['Phonenumber']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email,['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "contact-form.html", {'form': form})
```

> my form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
# from django.forms import contactForm
from .models import contactForm



class contactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 
    'form-control col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Name'}), label='')
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), label='')
    Phonenumber = forms.CharField(max_length=10, validators= [RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Mobile'}), label='')

    class contactForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:      
            model = contactForm
            fields = '__all__'
```

> my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class contactForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should post some code like your forms.py for clarification but seeing the error message, it shows django.forms import contactForm cannot import name 'contactForm' from 'django.forms'.Seems like contactForm is the name of the model on which you want to shape your form.
As that is model how can we import this from django.forms?
Use this code;

```
from .models import contactForm
from django.forms import modelForm #modelForm helps to create forms from models


class yourForm(modelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = contactForm #here we provide the name of the model from which the form is to be inherited
        fields = ('here_provide_the_name_of_the_fields_of_the_model_which_you_want_to_Include_in_the_form')
```

Different fields will be placed as different elements of the fields tuple.
If you want to include all the fields in the form;

```
fields = __all__
```

Comment: i did post my form.py as you said

Comment: First of all you don't need to import modelForm in your models.py. Though that is not any big issue. 2nd problem is that you are creating another class contactForm inside the pre-defined contactForm class which doesn't make any sense. You want to create fields as per your model but first you are creating them manually inside the contactForm and then you are again defining another class with same name inside the already created class and try to get the fields as per your model. What you actually need is replace the whole class with the class which you defined inside the contactForm class.

Comment: In short simply follow my answer.

Comment: My answer is  complete forms.py  for your project.

Comment: Again i want to mention that contactForm is a model created by you and doesn't belong to django.forms. So importing it from django.forms doesn't make any sense.